What rule, identity, or what have you explains why when making a recurrence relation, we are able to set $S = a_n = 0$?
Say that after subbing a power series into a homogeneous ODE such that
$L = (1-x^2)\frac{d^2}{dx^2} - 2x \frac{d}{dx} + \lambda$,
and after combining series, we have $S = \sum a_n$ where $$a_n = \Big[c_{n+2}(n+1)(n+2)+c_n\Big(\lambda-n(n+1)\Big)\Big]x^n$$ and that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = 0$$
Why are we then able to drop both the series and $x_n$ to get the following relation for any value of $n$: $$c_{n+2}(n+1)(n+2)+c_n\Big(\lambda-n(n+1)\Big) = 0$$? Technically we've just set $S = a_n = 0$. Now I can understand dropping $x^n$ if we're able to set $a_n = 0$ since we'd just divide $\frac{0}{x^n}$, I'm more confused about being able to isolate $a_n$ for any value of $n$ and being able to set this equal to $a_n = S$.
Is there a property that for any $a_n$ in $\sum a_n$ such that if $\sum a_n = 0$, then it must also be true that $$a_n = 0$$?

If $\sum_n A_nx^n=0$ for all $x,$ ten every $A_n=0.$ This has nothing to do with your complicated differential equation.

@ThomasAndrews That clears almost everything up. Also, thank you for showing to me the identity! Is there perhaps a name for this property or a proof which shows this to be the true? I must have forgotten seeing it in my previous calculus courses.

It is a property of power series, but I don't know that it has a name. There are even stronger versions of it - you don't need to know it for all $x,$ just an infinite bounded set of values $x.$

@ThomasAndrews Thank you!
